# C++ Taglib Cover Art from .flac and .asf files

Tags: c++, taglib

I build a project on VS2010 to parser some media files.Seen format spec from http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html but couldn't find out a way to get cover from asf and flac files,is there any ways?

Answer (score 4):

For Flac

```
TagLib::FLAC::File file = File("myfile.flac");  
const TagLib::List<TagLib::FLAC::Picture*>& picList = file.pictureList();
TagLib::FLAC::Picture* pic = picList[0];
```

For ASF

```
TagLib::ASF::File file = File("myfile.flac");
const TagLib::ASF::AttributeListMap& attrListMap = file->tag()->attributeListMap();
const TagLib::ASF::AttributeList& attrList = attrListMap["WM/Picture"];
TagLib::ASF::Picture pic = attrList[0].toPicture();
```

Rainmeter has a nice general implementation of cover art extraction for various fileformats in its NowPlayingPlugin located [here](https://github.com/rainmeter/rainmeter/blob/master/Library/NowPlaying/Cover.cpp).